# QMutex Access shared variable

Tags: c++, qt, mutex

write shared variable from different thread, I plan to do with QMutex, If I declared the mutex variable as an extern variable can I use it for read and write in separate two functions from  different source file?

like

**header.hpp**

```
extern QMutex mutex;
extern int  data;
```

**src1.cpp** // in one thread

```
int read(){
  int tmp;
  mutex.lock();
  tmp=data;
  mutex.unlock();
  return tmp;
}
```

**src2.cpp** // in another thread

```
void write(int val){
  mutex.lock();
  data=val;
  mutex.unlock();
}
```

Basically what I need is only one thread should access the shared variable for read or write at a time, in such a situation can I use mutex in this way?

Any help will be appreciated..
Thanks
Haris

Comment: If your real variable is of `int` type you don't need `mutex` at all, just use `QAtomicInteger`

Comment: Hi, I just write this to understanding my requirement, my shared variable will be a structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the principle is correct (assuming you meant to write `return tmp;` instead of `return data;`). Don't forget to define both `mutex` and `data` in exactly one source file (they can be in the same file or each in a different one).

However, it's generally better to use [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) classes (mutex lockers) instead of explicit locking and unlocking with these, the code would look like this:

```
int read()
{
  QMutexLocker l(&mutex);
  return data;
}

void write(int val)
{
  QMutexLocker l(&mutex);
  data = val;
}
```

The mutex locker locks the mutex in its constructor and unlocks it again in its destructor (which gets called automatically when `l` goes out of scope). This way, you can never forget to unlock the mutex, even in the presence of exceptions.

---

As a side note, if the data you're protecting is really just a single `int`, you might be better off using an atomic variable (such as `QAtomicInt`) instead of a variable+mutex pair.

Comment: Yes typing mistake, thanks for noticing , and  I don't know about RAII classes, but in that case no need to unlock the mutex ?, or it will be unlocked when exiting function.

Comment: Actually my data is a structure, this code just I write to indicate my situation is like this.

Comment: @Haris Yes, the mutex will be unlocked when the function ends (more precisely, when the locker goes out of scope), as the answer says.